# Deserializing Enum using borch_construct (Candy Machine Account Data)

Tags: python, candy-machine-v2, borsh

While deserializing account data from: https://explorer.solana.com/address/DZWdnz5VXYxGrutAFCUHzy5JkGc3kY4aGGv8oeT3nR26/anchor-account I am running into issues with the Enum object in borsh_construct.

When running, my output is always `Method.burnEveryTime()`, how do I deserialize and select the correct Enum?

```
from anchorpy.borsh_extension import BorshPubkey
from borsh_construct import CStruct, U8, Bool, U64, String, U16, I64, Vec, HashMap, Enum, TupleStruct, Option

pubkey = BorshPubkey

method = Enum(
    "burnEveryTime",
    "neverBurn",
    enum_name="Method",
)

s = CStruct("id" / U64, "authority" / pubkey, "wallet" / pubkey, "enabled" / U8, "redeemed" / U64,
                "data" /
                CStruct("uuid" / String,
                        "price" / U64,
                        "symbol" / String,
                        "fee" / U16,
                        "supply" / U64,
                        "mutable" / Bool,
                        "retain_auth" / Bool,
                        "go_live" / I64,
                        "has_end_settings" / U8,
                        "end_settings" / U8,
                        "creators" / Vec(CStruct("creator" / pubkey, "verified" / Bool, "share" / U8)),
                        "hidden" / U8,
                        "wl" / Option(TupleStruct(method, pubkey, Bool, Option(U64))),
                        "available" / U64
                        )
                )

metadata = s.parse(data)
```

Output:

```
Container: 
    id = 13649831137213787443
    authority = DXFeFYvb8qtQYPcQAbTAxJQztyBAzrMzxRfSGD3wNkr4
    wallet = 3StFdZpqVSKwmHJPkMzHb4LsvyTaR9Ffjq6LsBgpeAku
    enabled = 0
    redeemed = 1741
    data = Container: 
        uuid = u'100000' (total 6)
        price = 1000000000
        symbol = u'HRCC' (total 4)
        fee = 1111
        supply = 0
        mutable = True
        retain_auth = True
        go_live = 424474214401
        has_end_settings = 0
        end_settings = 0
        creators = ListContainer: 
            Container: 
                creator = 3StFdZpqVSKwmHJPkMzHb4LsvyTaR9Ffjq6LsBgpeAku
                verified = False
                share = 50
            Container: 
                creator = 2irfJjbj69m1jS6trBrRqcD1gGfRadNBoE7AS6QckuBQ
                verified = False
                share = 50
        hidden = 0
        wl = ListContainer: 
            Method.burnEveryTime()
            74KMFkaRxfYhWqZL7URkTGPTVyDwt5Gku3YCHaBwNCup
            True
            None
        available = 2222
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare it by `program.type['WhitelistMintMode'].BurnEveryTime()`.

https://kevinheavey.github.io/anchorpy/dynamic_client/examples
https://github.com/kevinheavey/anchorpy/blob/d042d74bcaf0b5cb9d32b79b8e98a821856d3213/tests/test_token_proxy.py#L195